# How to restore a deleted TFS Project Portal

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

Is there a way to restore an accidentally deleted project portal in TFS 2008?

Answer (score 2):

Only if you have a backup of the content database of the web application. It does mean any changes to that ALL project sites since the last backup will be lost. I suggest you backup those first. See this [link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=29397014&threadid=29397009) for more info on how to do it. Check out the links found through googling for [sharepoint restore accidentally deleted site](http://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+restore+accidentally+deleted+site)